# Can't use Thunder Stone with any Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

I'm trying to use a Thunder Stone, but I can't use it with any of the Pokémon on my team. Why can't I use it? Can it only be used with some specific Pokémon?

Comment: I feel like I coud answer this with basic access to the pokemon wiki and I havnt properly played pokemon since silver.. but yes. only very specific pokemon react to a thunderstone. Pikachu and Eevee are examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Thunder Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolutionary_stone#Thunder_Stone) is one of a group of items known as Evolutionary Stones. Using one on a certain type of Pokémon will cause it to evolve. In Generation 3, the Thunder Stone can be used with the following Pokémon:

- Pikachu, evolving into Raichu
- Eevee, evolving into Jolteon

Starting in Generation 5, it can also be used to evolve Eelektrik into Eelektross.

Note that Eevee has multiple evolution options, including others from using a Fire Stone or a Water Stone. Consider carefully which form you want for an Eevee. Stone evolutions also usually cause a Pokémon to no longer learn new moves on level-up (Eevee being an exception), so be careful not to use it too early unless you plan to resort to TMs for moves.

Comment: Ninja'd by 7 seconds, HA!

Comment: @user1337, note that he has put a lot more effort into the answer than simply quoting a wikipedia. this is what we look for

Comment: @Timelord64 Well, I didn't really mean it in a condescending manner. You think that's why I've got the downvote?

Comment: @user1337, you got downvoted for providi g a copy paste answer, compared to an actual written-by-a-human answer

Comment: @Timelord64 If an answer doesn't provide enough information, then it's reasonable to downvote for bad quality. I get the feeling I would have a valid answer by your suggested standard if I replaced "Quoting the Bulbapedia entry" with "The Thunder Stone does the following:", regardless of how similar the phrasing of what I wrote is to what the wiki says. Correct?

Comment: @user1337, incorrect, as it has already been done in the above question. duplicate answers < eiki copies < actual thought out answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40106/discussion-between-user1337-and-timelord64).

Answer (score 1):

The [Thunder Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Evolutionary_stone) does the following:

> Causes Pikachu to evolve into Raichu.
>
> Causes Eevee to evolve into Jolteon.
>
> Causes Eelektrik to evolve into Eelektross.

Comment: wait, I think you took my comment to literally. I feel like there is definetly evolutions past those in blue, red and green.

Comment: @Timelord64 Nope, that is literally every Thunder Stone evolution.

Comment: wow. Thunderstone is the stone of the 90s.